# How to Determine a Route With Path Value

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

Please, I am having some kinda challenge solving this scenario.
Whenever my app starts, it goes to a DummyComponent which has no url path value (http://localhost:4200/). This have just have two buttons, login and register. Pending on whichever button you click on; it navigates to the page.

Lets assume a user clicks on the login button to auth into the system, once successful, the user is redirected to the dashboard component => http://localhost:4200/dashboard.

Now, even when the user is logged in and manually change the url to http://localhost:/4200. This has no path value, how do I redirect the user back to http://localhost:4200/dashboard

I understand I can use the canActivate guard to protect my route, but the challenge I am having is; how can I determine when a user visit a url without a path value i.e http://localhost:4200/ (when logged in) so that I can redirect the user back to dashboard? …. But again, when the user is not logged in and visit the url without a path, it should go straight to the initial DummyComponent.

Here is how my route looks like:

```
const routes4: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: DummyComponent},
   {
     path: '',
     runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
     canActivate: [AuthGuard],
     children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
       { path: 'user/list', component: PatientsComponent },
       { path: 'user/new', component: PatientComponent },
       { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
     ]
   },
];
****
canActivate(): boolean {
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        return true;
      }
      this.pnotifyService.error('Error', 'You do not have sufficient permission');
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
  }
```

I did some research but couldn’t lay my hands on a scenario like mine.

Any idea on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another gaurd to redirect the user to proper path based on your condition

Something like this:

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate }    from '@angular/router';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class RedirectGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {

    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
         // when user is logged in you redirect it to dashboard url
         this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
         return true;
    }
  }
 //Constructor 
 constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService) { }
}
```

Now you can use it in your path like this:

```
const routes4: Routes = [
   {path: '', component: DummyComponent},
   {
     path: '',
     runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
     canActivate: [AuthGuard, RedirectGuard],
     children: [
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
       { path: 'user/list', component: PatientsComponent },
       { path: 'user/new', component: PatientComponent },
       { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
     ]
   },
];
```

**Update:**

You can re-use your existing code to achieve this behavior

Something like this:

```
canActivate(): boolean {
      if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {
        this.router.navigate['/dashboard'] //redirect if the user is logged in
        return true;
      }
      this.pnotifyService.error('Error', 'You do not have sufficient permission');
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: @Asim...many thanks for the response. I tried this solution, but my tab freezes and keeps spinning without rendering the dashboard. When I checked the console, I got a throttling warning which keeps looping endlessly.....
Again looking at the solution, it seems both the AuthGuard and RedirectGuard clashes for reasons which I can't figure out now.